# Python : Get elements using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am using this website with selenium : [link](https://www.deepl.com/translator)

And am having some issues trying to : select language for input and output, output text and language type(formel or informel or automatique )

[image]

**my code so far:**

```
# Make imports

# Define text to translate
text_to_translate = 'hello this is me not him'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

TARGET_LANGUAGES = ({"french": 1,
                     "english": 2,
                     "german": 3,
                     "spanish": 4,
                     "portuguese": 5,
                     "italian": 6,
                     "dutch": 7,
                     "polish": 8,
                     "russian": 9})
#input is working good 
input_text_xpath = """//*[@id="dl_translator"]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/textarea""" 
output_text_xpath = """//*[@id="dl_translator"]/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/textarea"""
language_select_xpath = """//*[@id="dl_translator"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/button/div"""
target_language_xpath = f"""//*[@id="dl_translator"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/button[{target_language=TARGET_LANGUAGES["english"]}]"""
# Start a Selenium driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)


# Reach the deepL website
deepl_url = 'https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator'
driver.get(deepl_url)

# Get thie inupt_area
input_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath(input_text_xpath)

# Send the text
input_area.clear()
input_area.send_keys(text_to_translate)

# Wait for translation to appear on the web page
time.sleep(2)

# Get copybutton and click on it
content= driver.find_element_by_xpath(output_text_xpath).text
# Display results
print('_'*50)
print('Original    :', text_to_translate)
print('Translation :', content)
print('_'*50)
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: do you get error message ? You have to describe it. `having some issues` is not enough. Don't expect that we will run code to see it. Maybe elements are in `<frame>` and then browser treats it as separated element and you have to use `switch_to`

Comment: @furas   i get no error message, i just get nothing back from it.

Comment: @furas can u just help me locate these elements from the website i added the code just to not get vote for closing or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target text is in `div` instead of `textarea` - and it has also `id` so `xpath` is short

```
'//div[@id="target-dummydiv"]'
```

But I couldn't get text using

```
content.text   # empty list
```

but I could get it with

```
content.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

---

Because I used page with Polish language so I had lists with Polish names - ie. `"Angielski"` instead of `"English"` so I couldn't use names on list to select language and I used

for source language

```
@dl-test="translator-lang-option-en"
@dl-test="translator-lang-option-fr"
@dl-test="translator-lang-option-pl"
```

for target language

```
@dl-test="translator-lang-option-en-EN"
@dl-test="translator-lang-option-fr-FR"
@dl-test="translator-lang-option-pl-PL"
```

Some languages show alternative translations which I could get with

```
'//button[@class="lmt__translations_as_text__text_btn"]'
```

It needed only to skip empty strings.

---

Result:

```
__________________________________________________
Original    : hello this is me not him
Translation : Bonjour, c'est moi, pas lui.
Alternative : Bonjour, c'est moi et non lui.
Alternative : Allo, c'est moi, pas lui.
__________________________________________________
```

Full working code with other changes

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Define text to translate
source_text = 'hello this is me not him'

LANGUAGES = ({  # [source, target]
    "french":     ['fr', 'fr-FR'],
    "english":    ['en', 'en-GB'],
    "german":     ['de', 'de-DE'],
    "spanish":    ['es', 'es-ES'],
    "portuguese": ['pt', 'pt-PT'],
    "italian":    ['it', 'it-IT'],
    "dutch":      ['da', 'da-DA'],
    "polish":     ['pl', 'pl-PL'],
    "russian":    ['ru', 'ru-RU']
})

#source_xpath = '//div[@dl-test="translator-source"]'
#target_xpath = '//div[@dl-test="translator-target"]'

source_input_text_xpath  = '//textarea[@dl-test="translator-source-input"]' 
#target_input_text_xpath  = '//textarea[@dl-test="translator-target-input"]' 

#target_output_text_xpath = '//div[@id="source-dummydiv"]
target_output_text_xpath = '//div[@id="target-dummydiv"]'

source_button_xpath = '//button[@dl-test="translator-source-lang-btn"]'
target_button_xpath = '//button[@dl-test="translator-target-lang-btn"]'

lang = LANGUAGES["english"][0]   # 0 - source
source_language_xpath = f'//div[@dl-test="translator-source-lang-list"]//button[@dl-test="translator-lang-option-{lang}"]'

#lang = LANGUAGES["polish"][1]    # 1 - target
lang = LANGUAGES["french"][1]   # 1 - target
target_language_xpath = f'//div[@dl-test="translator-target-lang-list"]//button[@dl-test="translator-lang-option-{lang}"]'


# Start a Selenium driver

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 1200)

# Reach the deepL website
url = 'https://www.deepl.com/en/translator'   
#url = 'https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator'
#url = 'https://www.deepl.com/pl/translator'
driver.get(url)

# Select languages
driver.find_element_by_xpath(source_button_xpath).click()    # open list
time.sleep(0.1)                                              # wait for list
driver.find_element_by_xpath(source_language_xpath).click()  # click option on list (maybe it will need to scroll)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(target_button_xpath).click()    # open list
time.sleep(0.1)                                              # wait for list
driver.find_element_by_xpath(target_language_xpath).click()  # click option on list (maybe it will need to scroll)

# Select Automatic
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="lmt__formalitySwitch__toggler"]').click()
time.sleep(0.1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="lmt__formalitySwitch__menu_items"]//button[@_dl-connected="1"][3]').click()

# Get thie source inupt_area
input_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath(source_input_text_xpath)

# Send the text
input_area.clear()
input_area.send_keys(source_text)

# Wait for translation to appear on the web page
time.sleep(3)

# Get target text and alternatives
target_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(target_output_text_xpath).get_attribute('innerHTML')
target_alternative_text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@class="lmt__translations_as_text__text_btn"]')

# Display results
print('_'*50)
print('Original    :', source_text)
print('Translation :', target_text.strip())

for item in target_alternative_text:
    text = item.text.strip()
    if text:
        print('Alternative :', text)

print('_'*50)
```

Result:

Comment: thank you soo much, it's working like a charm, i did manage to have a working version in normal mode but when i switch to headless it doesn't work, but ur code is working perfectly in headless, thanks again.

Comment: I added selection `Auotmatic` which I forgot. Now I also added `driver.set_window_size(1400, 1200)` because it headless mode had problem on my computer - window was too small and it clicked in `cookie message`

Comment: i am just getting confused why i was getting blank text in the output and now with inner html it's working?

Answer (score 1):

This is the xpath to open the language list:

```
//button[@dl-test='translator-source-lang-btn']
```

This is the xpath for selecting the language:

```
f"//div[@dl-test='translator-source-lang-list']/button[text()='{language}']"
```

This is the xpath  to open the translate into list

```
//button[@dl-test='translator-target-lang-btn']
```

This is the xpath to select the translate language

```
 f"//button[contains(@dl-test,'translator-lang-option') and text() = '{translate}']"
```

This is the xpath to open the formal/informal list

```
//button[@class = 'lmt__formalitySwitch__toggler']
```

This is the xpath to select the formal/informal options. Replace 'Automatic' with the option you want.

```
(//div[@class='lmt__formalitySwitch__menu_items']//button[text()='Automatic'])[0]
```

So first click the list, then pass in the list item you want to select

```
language = 'Danish'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@dl-test='translator-source-lang-btn']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@dl-test='translator-source-lang-list']/button[text()='{language}']").click()
```

Output text

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lmt__textarea_container lmt__textarea_container_no_shadow']).text
```

Comment: what about the output text please!

Comment: I missed that. That would be: //div[@class='lmt__textarea_container lmt__textarea_container_no_shadow']

Comment: Oh I see, you need the other elements from output. I'll update my code.

Comment: actually for the output text i get only the suggested translations not the actual one.

Comment: Try this xpath://textarea[@dl-test='translator-target-input']